# Visual Studio 2008 difference between database in App_Data and Server Explorer Data Connection

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio-2008, database-connection

I've recently starting learning asp.net and MVC and would be grateful for some clarification on working with data in an application. More specifically, what is the difference between adding a new sql server database item to the App_Data folder and creating a database connection in the Server Explorer window? If I add a new database in the App_Data folder am I still able to work with this database in SSMS or I can I only work with it through Visual Studio?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If you have the *.mdf placed in App_Data folder

```
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="ConnectionName"
    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DatabaseName.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

> it will work if you change your file location.
>   server explorer connection will be static.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are there no other pros and cons to either and is there a preferred method?